# Как убрать окно Python Turtle Graphics , и поставить созданную черепашку на главное окно?

Tags: python, turtle, qinputdialog

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Объясняю, как вы видите у меня есть маленькое окошко для создания черепашки. Но как только я ввожу имя черепашки
'имя = turtleTurtle()' у меня вылазит окно Python Turtle Graphics.
Как убрать его и поставить черепашку на главное окно?

```
from ast import Global
from pyclbr import Class
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import*
from random import randint
import turtle
import sys


######################################

app = QApplication([])
main_win = QWidget()
main_win.setWindowTitle('GOнки 1 - 8 player')
main_win.resize(1200, 1080)
main_win.setStyleSheet('.QWidget {background-image: 
url(kproject.jpg);}')


################## Widgetы ####################

btn_add_player = QPushButton('Добавить гонщика')
zanavo = QPushButton('Заново')
start = QPushButton('start')
Name_game = QLabel('G O н щ и к')
Delite = QPushButton('Удалить гонщика')


################### Лэйауты и их расположение 
####################

layout_main1 = QHBoxLayout()
layout_main4 = QHBoxLayout()
layout_main2 = QHBoxLayout()
layout_main3 = QHBoxLayout()
layout_main_V = QVBoxLayout()
layout_main_f_1 = QHBoxLayout()
layout_main_f_2 = QHBoxLayout()
layout_main_f_3 = QHBoxLayout()


layout_main1.addWidget(btn_add_player)
layout_main1.addWidget(zanavo)
layout_main2.addWidget(Name_game)
layout_main3.addWidget(start)
layout_main4.addWidget(Delite)



layout_main_V.addLayout(layout_main1)
layout_main_V.addLayout(layout_main2)
layout_main_V.addLayout(layout_main3)
layout_main_V.addLayout(layout_main4)

main_win.setLayout(layout_main_V)

main_win.show()
################## Классы и функции ######################
class ADD_PLAYER1(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(200,100)
        self.btn = QPushButton('Добавить player', self)
        self.btn.move(50, 30)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.evt_btn_clicked)


    def evt_btn_clicked(self):
        Spisok = []
        foorma_spisok ['arrow','square','triangle','classic']
        coolor_spisok = ['green','blue','purple','gold']
        s_name, b_ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Выбор 
гонщика', 'Введите имя гонщика',)
        if b_ok:
            s_name = turtle.Turtle()
            Spisok.append(s_name)
            s_forma, b_ok = QInputDialog.getItem(self, 'Выбор 
гонщика', 'Введите форму гонщика', foorma_spisok, 
editable=False)
            if b_ok:
                s_name.shape(s_forma)
                s_color, b_ok = QInputDialog.getItem(self, 
'Выбор гонщика', 'Введите цвет гонщика', coolor_spisok, 
editable=False)
                if b_ok:
                    s_name.color(s_color)
                else:
                    QMessageBox.critical('Canceled','User 
have clicked "Cancel"')
            else:
                QMessageBox.critical('Canceled','User have clicked "Cancel"')
    else:
        QMessageBox.critical('Canceled','User have clicked 
"Cancel"')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app_addplayer = QApplication([])
    add_player1 = ADD_PLAYER1()
    add_player1.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
##############################   END   
#################################

app.exec_()
```

Comment: знаю , скопировал криво ,но надеюсь понятно.

Comment: Создайте Canvas в главном окне, потом создайте черепашку через `turtle.RawTurtle(canvas)`, тогда она будет привязана к существующему холсту на вашем окне. См. документацию: https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.RawTurtle P.S. черепаха будет работать только с Canvas из tkinter. Если его можно создать на окне созданном через Qt, то вам повезло.